# Will workndows script host run script in Chrome browser

Tags: wsh

```
Dim Wsh

Set objShell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set objExec = objShell.Exec("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://<internal company VPN address>")

Wscript.Sleep 1000

objShell.AppActivate("<Title page>")

Wscript.Sleep 1000


Wsh.SendKeys "<username>"


Wscript.Sleep 1000

Wsh.SendKeys "{TAB}"

Wsh.Sendkeys "<password>"


Wscript.Sleep 1000

Wsh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

I am getting a WSH "objectRequired ."     runtime error on trying to run the following script.

What happens is  :

Chrome Browser opens up correctly to Chrome and the 
included https address ( internal vpn address )

However it stops with the stated runtime error just prior to the 
because the cursor is not focused in that text box.

My understanding is that WSH cannot treat Chrome browser and an object and that
java script would work however I need advice or starte code to help me along.

Objective is to

1 . set focus on the username text box then

2. tab to password text box then hit the
3. enter key and log in

Comment: Please excuse the disorganizing post.

Comment: Here is a more understandable question. Thanks.